# What are the piano notes of Hum Ko Tumse Ho Gaya hai pyaar kya kare?

Tags: piano, notation

What are the piano notes of Hum Ko Tumse Ho Gaya hai pyaar kya kare?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Music SE. I’m afraid this kind of question is considered off topic here (even if you ask three times :)). As far as I understand you’re either looking for a pointer to published sheet music or a transcription of a song. You *might* want to try your luck on some dedicated fan forum. This here is sadly not the place for such requests.

Comment: @Lazy hey bro I only wat to Piano notes of this song I can not  find  over the internet so i Post here it's indian hindi song...